# Validate Token using adal4j?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, adal4j

After recieving a token using acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode. How can I verify the token against the azure AD?

```
@Override
public void validateToken(String jwt) {

    //how to verify
}
```

Comment: The ID Token, or the Access Token?

Comment: Its the access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to.  When you get a token from ADAL, you're supposed to send it to a web API that accepts that token.  That web API does the validation.

If you want to get a token and validate it in your app to do sign-in, then we recommend you use OpenID Connect, which results in an id_token that you can validate.